# What are the things to consider while using VRMLLoader in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Trying to load different sample VRML(Ver. 2.0) files using VRMLLoader in THREE.js(Ver. r66) and following are the issues which I faced:

1. Object length is not defined error at line no. 125(angles object) and at line no. 151(for color object) [VRMLLoader.js]

   - Should I have to check for any list of VRML nodes which must be there in VRML file before rendering?
2. In my project, I have a VRML file of size 20MB. When I tried loading it the browser crash message came in Google chrome browser

   - is there any method using which I can load such heavy files in THREE.js?

Thanks in advance,
Pradeep

Comment: isn't vrml a bit outdated? Are you sure the file is not damaged or something?

Comment: Hi, the requirement is to load VRML files, cant't help and we are able to load these files in other tools.